TikTok comment input not visible on puppeteer but visible in browser
The TikTok comment input is not visible on puppeteer, but visible in browser.
Browser screenshot
Puppeteer screenshot
I have tried to zoom out and to adjust the viewport without results.
I have written the code, but am not able to find the selector as previously mentioned.
async function commentVideo(page, videoElement) {
const commentInputSelector = '[data-e2e="comment-input"]';
await page.waitForSelector(commentInputSelector, { visible: true
});

const comment = await generateComment();
await page.focus(commentInputSelector);
await page.keyboard.type(comment, { delay: 100 });

await page.evaluate(() => {
const postBtn = document.querySelector('[data-e2e="comment- 
post"]');
postBtn.click();
});

console.log("Comment posted:", comment);
}

I have shared a runnable minimal reproducible example with a site and all variables and functions defined
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import StealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
import puppeteerStandard from "puppeteer";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
dotenv.config();

function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const siteLink = "";
const emailAddress = "";
const password = "";

// Function to handle login
async function loginToTikTok(page) {
await page.goto(siteLink);
await page.waitForSelector("#loginContainer");
await page.type('[placeholder="Email or username"]', 
emailAddress);
await page.type('[placeholder="Password"]', password);
await page.click('[data-e2e="login-button"]');
await page.waitForSelector("#captcha_container");
}

async function main() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
executablePath: puppeteerStandard.executablePath(),
headless: false,
args: ["--window-size=850,1000", "--no-sandbox"],
});
const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
await page.setViewport({ width: 850, height: 1000 });

await loginToTikTok(page);

await page.waitForSelector(".captcha_verify_container", { 
hidden: true });

await sleep(5000);
console.log("no container");

//await post(page);

// Navigate back to the For You Page
console.log("Navigating back to the For You Page...");
await page.goto("https://www.tiktok.com/foryou");
console.log("Arrived at the For You Page.");

// Pause to ensure the page is loaded
console.log("Pausing to allow page load...");
await sleep(5000);

// Click on first video to open up video player
const videoDiv = await page.$$('[data-e2e="recommend-list-item- 
container"]');
if (videoDiv.length > 0) {
const firstVideoElement = videoDiv[0];
const videoSelector = "video";
const videoElementHandle = await 
firstVideoElement.$(videoSelector);

if (videoElementHandle) {
await videoElementHandle.click();
} else {
console.error("No video element found within the video 
container.");
}
} else {
console.error("No videos found on the page.");
}
}


Please share a runnable [mcve] with a site and all variables and functions defined. Thanks.

Thank you for the tip! I have added an example.

Thanks--I'm still seeing SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant. (57:32). Can you fix that and run your code through Prettier so it's indented? You can remove both of the old code snippets and replace them with the updated one.

When dealing with Puppeteer and elements not appearing as they do in a regular browser, you often need to adjust settings related to how the page is rendered and detected. Here’s a checklist:

Full Page Load: Ensure the page has fully loaded before querying elements:
await page.goto('URL', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


Viewport and User-Agent: Set a realistic viewport and User-Agent to mimic a typical browser:
await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
await page.setUserAgent('User-Agent string here');


Anti-Bot Measures: Disable features that websites use to detect automation:
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ['--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled']
});


Debugging with Screenshots: Capture what Puppeteer is rendering:
await page.screenshot({path: 'debug-screenshot.png'});


Element Interaction: Ensure your script waits for elements to be visible and interactable:
await page.waitForSelector('[data-e2e="comment-input"]', { visible: true });



Here’s an updated function that incorporates these elements:
async function commentVideo(page, videoUrl) {
    await page.goto(videoUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 ...');
    await page.waitForSelector('[data-e2e="comment-input"]', { visible: true });
    await page.focus('[data-e2e="comment-input"]');
    await page.keyboard.type('Your comment here', { delay: 100 });
    await page.click('[data-e2e="comment-post"]');
    console.log("Comment posted.");
}

